# Как использовать данный task?

Tags: svg, gulp, svg-спрайт

Добавили в gulp js таск, не очень понимаю логику и как использовать

```
gulp.task('sprites', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/icons/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSymbols({
            title: false,
            id: 'icon_%f',
            className: '.icon_%f',
        }))
        .pipe(gulpIf(/\.css$/, gulp.dest('app/css')))
        .pipe(gulpIf(/\.svg$/, rename('icon.svg')))
        .pipe(gulpIf(/\.svg$/, gulp.dest('dist/img')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем добавили? 
Судя по коду, этот таск должен группировать все изображения svg из папки `app/icons` в один файл `icon.svg` и копировать его в `dist/img`. Хотя не очень понятно зачем там строчка `pipe(gulpIf(/\.css$/, gulp.dest('app/css'))`